# How to troubleshoot no "kinetic" scrolling on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I have a web app using React and the "kinetic" scrolling in mobile Chrome/Safari does not work. Not sure if that's the correct term, but when I flick up or down, the scrolling stops immediately rather than continuing and gradually slowing down and stopping. On other web sites/apps, if you tap the title bar the page will scroll to the top. Mine does not. Scrolling behaves as expected on all desktop browsers.

How can I fix/troubleshoot this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue...I had a random `overflow: hidden` applied to a `<div>` element which wrapped all of my content.